# Webpack build production with configurable URL

Tags: javascript, webpack

Can I configure webpack to read the `baseURL` from an external `config.js` file and on build does not bundle that config file, but include in the project, to be configurable?

Comment: You should have only one domain. That means that your request made by the app should go on the same domain that the app. Perhaps you have to put a proxy on your server. You really need to avoid cross-domain request.

Comment: @Kornflexx Uhm… testing, staging, production servers…? CDN configurations…? In the real world, something like this is actually necessary.

Comment: @Deceze so use a cors extension in your webbrowser. The only limitation of an extension like this is a flash player. Be smart, don't do useless things.